# Code behind property update from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javaScript function Func() in my user control which updates hidden field value.
I would like to further SET this hiddenfield value to code behind property in a same javascript function (to access in parent aspx.vb page) to access in ASPX.VB without postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    function func(id) {

        HFTargetSign = id;
        alert(HFTargetSign);
    }
</script>
```

Can some one suggest me to implement this ?

Comment: So, you want your JavaScript to reference a property of your code-behind? If so, you'll want to search for something like *"JavaScript and VB.Net AJAX"* in Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign value from code behind to JavaScript then you can do it in two ways

1. Using hidden fields
2. Or using Protected type variable

   ```
   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected string Variable_codebehind;
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Variable_codebehind = "Something";
       }
   }
   ```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
    <head runat="server"> 
    <title>Ashish's Blog</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
             ////Getting variable from asp.net code behind  
              alert("<%=Variable_codebehind %>");
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>  
    </div>  
    </form>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Other Option:

- since your hidden field is a server control it could be that the ID
  is getting generated to something other than filesPercentage
  (probably something like `ctl00_ctl00_filesPercentage`)
- You may need to apply the generated client ID to your javascript `document.getElementById("<%=filesPercentage.ClientID%>").value;`
     Or use another way of selecting the hidden value, such as $('[hidden's parent element] input[type="hidden"]').val()

Comment: For somereason i am not able to format the code it always break when i try to format it, Not sure if there is some issue with stackoverflow or its just my browser

Comment: I want to do it other way, from JavaScript to Web Method.